# ASP.NET Core How to bind data from body

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Postman and trying to send post json data in the body.
[How Postman request looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXsRI.png)

**This is my api method**

```
 [HttpPost("attach")]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public async Task<IActionResult> AttachToBuilding([FromBody]AttachmentDto dto)
```

After sending request dto always null.
[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTUMj.png)

**This is my model**

```
public class AttachmentDto
{
    public string Identity { get; set; }
    public Guid BuildingId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UniqueDeviceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ApartmentNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AgreementNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int FloorNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**My Startup.cs** ConfigurationServices method

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        services.AddOptions();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                        builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    });
        });

        services.AddDbContext<KskEfContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnectionName)));

        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

        AddDependencies(services);

        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddFormatterMappings()
            //for aspe.net core  need to add explicitly the Api Explorer service (swagger)
            .AddApiExplorer()
            .AddDataAnnotations()
        .AddJsonFormatters(options => options.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());


        services.AddAutoMapper();

        //Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "KSK api", Version = "v1" });
            c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
        });
    }
```

I find my configuration correct and I designed my api method like in previeos ASP.NET WebApi nothing extraordinary. It might be problem with framework version.

**My dependencies from project.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"AutoMapper": "5.2.0",
"AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection": "1.2.0",
"Ksk.DataAccess": "1.0.0-*",
"Ksk.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Swashbuckle.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc1"
},
```

**My request details**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Length:280
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://localhost:5000
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://localhost:5000/docs/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36

Request Payload
{
  "Identity": "AST-25",
  "BuildingId": "",
  "FirstName": "Petr",
  "LastName": "Petrov",
  "MiddleName": "Petrovich",
  "Phone": "+77012223344",
  "UniqueDeviceId": "68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067",
  "ApartmentNumber": 20,
  "AgreementNumber": 292,
  "FloorNumber": 5
}
```

Comment: Show your json post

Comment: Request details added

Comment: Are you using any middleware before the MVC middleware, which read from the request stream? Because request stream is forward only and can't be rewinded (as it directly reads the data sent from browser), so if you read the datastream, you end up at the end of the stream and when the model binder tries to read it, it has no data

Comment: No, I am not. First middleware that I am using is MVC

Comment: @user2148690 you seem to be mixing mvc and web api. if this is meant to be web api replace `[Route("attach")][HttpPost]` with just `[HttpPost("attach")]` read up on attribute routing here as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing

Comment: Nkosi, Yes I tried it, but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the value of buidingId by `null` or `"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"` because the controller can't convert an empty `string` to `Guid`.

Comment: A good option would also be to use a view model in this case ... I understand it's 1 more class but it helps, specially if you are exposing this to external clients ... you don't want to leave room for mass assignment or over posting issues ... I upvoted the answer just cause it will work but personally I would go with a VM ...